# Django post-office: unable to open email attachement

Tags: python, django, email, django-email

I've written a django view that loads a number of PDF files and combines them into a .zipfile.

I dont want to save the object on the server, so I am using StringIO()

This is done with the following code:

```
zip_buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
        summary_filename = 'summary' + str(user) + '.pdf'
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
            for file in attachements:

                    zf.write(str(settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + '/' + str(file[0].file),
                             file[1] + '.' + str(file[0].file).split('.')[-1])

            zf.writestr(summary_filename, pdf)
```

When I was debugging the code I had it return the object as a download in the browser through the following code

```
response = HttpResponse(zip_buffer.getvalue(), 'application/x-zip-compressed')
    return response
```

This all works as intended, when I click the button a .zip file is downloaded by the browser that contains all of the information.

The problems started when I wanted to email the file as well. I am using [Django post-office](https://github.com/ui/django-post_office)

And intitally tried sending the email with the following command:

```
attachment_file = zip_buffer.getvalue()

send_email([requester.email], email_template
               context, attachments={'summary.pdf': attachment_file})
```

The attachement file is exactly the same as the one I supplied to the browser, yet this causes the following exception:

```
file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
```

I then tried something different:

```
send_email([requester.email], 'userprofile_summary', requester.profile.tenant,
                   context, attachments={
                'summary.zip': ContentFile(attachment_file)})
```

Now this works in the sense that the email gets sent with an attachement, but the file that I receive is unopenable. Its like its corrupted, both OSX, Windows and Linux computers where unable to open the file.

I am currently at a loss at what to do / what is the problem. The file worked perfectly in the browser, yet it crashes when I try to email it. When I encapsulate it into a 'ContentFile()' class it returns a file that cannot be opened.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, it was a mistake in my code. For future readers with similar problems:

I forgot to add a `zf.close()` after the `zf.writestr(summary_filename, pdf)` , though the browser was able to handle this mistake, Django is more carefull - leading to my problems. Adding the close() command solved it.